# Does the sleep method work insied a dramatiq actor?

Tags: sleep, background-process, actor, worker, dramatiq

If I made a function as a dramatiq actor and  put it to  sleep for 10 minutes before performing certain tasks,does it wait  for the sleep to be completed before performing those tasks or does it perform the tasks directly ignoring the sleep method completely?

I am Just confused if the sleep method works inside a dramatiq actor or not?